# Is it possible to support Python binding for AddJoint that takes X_PF, X_BM as arguments?

Tags: python, drake

I am trying to translate [`make_acrobot_plant.cc`](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/multibody/benchmarks/acrobot/make_acrobot_plant.cc) to Python. To add the `elbow` joint, I need to pass in the `X_PF` and `X_BM` into `AddJoint` (as in [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/77a7b9437331f1540666b9089395b53da403e4fa/multibody/benchmarks/acrobot/make_acrobot_plant.cc#L83)).

This is supported in the C++ interface as in [`JointType`](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/dd6442960b3c4d9f3c89c203194888ad09de2fa7/multibody/tree/multibody_tree.h#L484). But the current Python binding only supports the [`AddJoint` without `X_PF` and `X_BM`](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/77a7b9437331f1540666b9089395b53da403e4fa/bindings/pydrake/multibody/plant_py.cc#L194), Is there a work around?

Comment: FTR Russ and Alejandro's answers below are 100% correct. As you may have noticed, the full spelling of the C++ code is `plant->AddJoint<RevoluteJoint>(...)`, so you still have to specify the type. In Python, it's decoupled, i.e. `plant.AddJoint(RevoluteJoint(...))`. If you're at all curious about this feature in C++, see [parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

Comment: Went ahead and made a PR about this: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/13134. Feel free to comment if you think anything there is unclear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add them by constructing the joint first.  See, e.g.:
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/bindings/pydrake/multibody/test/plant_test.py#L401

Answer (score 1):

I'm not expert on Python bindings, but at least let me give you an option.
The C++ API is suggar for defining frames F (affixed to P) and M (affixed to B) for you. You can accomplish this from the Python API using AddFrame. Something like so:

```py
# Parent body P in the API
arm = plant.GetBodyByName("arm")
# Child body B in the API
forearm = plant.GetBodyByName("forearm")
# Define frame F in the API.
arm_elbow_frame = plant.AddFrame(FixedOffsetFrame(name="F", P=arm.body_frame(), X_PF, model_instance=None))

# Say M = B. In that case you don't need a new frame.
elbow = plant.AddJoint(RevoluteJoint(name="elbow", frame_on_parent=arm_elbow_frame, frame_on_child=forearm.body_frame(), axis_F=[0, 0, 1], damping=0.))
```